# Can't add class to a tr in table generated from CSV file in Papaparse

Tags: jquery, csv

Trying to make a table out of csv file, which i would later manipulate with jquery. Papaparse seems to be the easiest to use for data extraction from the csv. It generated the table fine. But for some reason, I can't even add a class to a tr. Here is my code.

```
function arrayToTable(tableData) {
    var table = $('<table></table>');
    $(tableData).each(function (i, rowData) {
        var row = $('<tr></tr>');
        $(rowData).each(function (j, cellData) {
            row.append($('<td>'+cellData+'</td>'));
        });
        table.append(row);
    });
    return table;
}

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "data/late.csv",
    success: function (data) {
        $('body .tableclass').append(arrayToTable(Papa.parse(data).data));
    }
});

$(window).load(function(){
    $(".tableclass table tbody tr").each(function(){
       $(this).addClass("trclass");
      }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're applying the class before your data has finished loading. To fix, do the following:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "data/late.csv",
    success: function (data) {
        $('body .tableclass').append(arrayToTable(Papa.parse(data).data));
        $(".tableclass table tbody tr").each(function(){
           $(this).addClass("trclass");
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, this is only an example. In the end, I want to be able to pull data from that table and dynamically style it.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that and how my answer doesn't solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your onload is firing before actual table is created. 
$(".tableclass table tbody tr") length might be zero at that time.

Edit: As you need to call these function multiple time and with different set of customization, I would say call you ajax function from another function, and add you callback function as parameter. Call this callback function after your ajax success

```
function arrayToTable(CallbackFunction)
{
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "data/late.csv",
    success: function (data) {
        $('body .tableclass').append(arrayToTable(Papa.parse(data).data));
        CallbackFunction();
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to launch that code on table load?